# Tableview scrollbar

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, scrollpane, scrollbars

I am having FXML file which has tableview, and that contains the dynamic rows and columns so when even more rows or columns are there it should show scrollbar.

If I decrease/increase the height/width scroll should come accordingly.

My fxml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections ?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>

<VBox minWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="550.0" stylesheets="@CLsMain.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>

        <HBox minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="20.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView>
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@wellsFargoLogo.png" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="810.0" minWidth="-Infinity" style="-fx-background-color: lightGray;" text="FX Continous Linked Settlement" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="16.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </HBox>

        <HBox alignment="CENTER" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="58.0">
            <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="55.0" text="Config" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <ComboBox prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="110.0" promptText="Default Config" />
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="16.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" />
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Quick Links" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <ComboBox prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="90.0" promptText="CLS GUI" />
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="17.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true" />
                <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Resend" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
            </children>
        </HBox>

        <TabPane minWidth="-Infinity" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Trade Blotter">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="515.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Payment">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="58.0" prefWidth="515.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="I/O Swap">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Exception">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Non-Repudiation">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Maintenance">
                    <content>
                        <AnchorPane>
                            <children>
                                <VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                                    <children>
                                        <HBox alignment="CENTER" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="800.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Select table" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textOverrun="CENTER_ELLIPSIS" wrapText="true">
                                                    <font><Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" /></font>
                                                </Label>
                                                <ComboBox fx:id="clsTableConfigComboBox" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="180.0" promptText="Select Table"></ComboBox>                                              
                                            </children>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <ToolBar>
                                            <items>
                                                <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="31.0" minWidth="-Infinity">
                                                    <children>
                                                        <!-- <ImageView>
                                                            <image>
                                                                <Image url="@tabClosedLarge.png" />
                                                            </image>
                                                        </ImageView> -->
                                                        <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAddHandler" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="59.0" text=" Add " textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
                                                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="16.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" />
                                                        <!-- <ImageView fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="24.0">
                                                            <image>
                                                                <Image url="@tabOpenLarge.png" />
                                                            </image>
                                                        </ImageView> -->
                                                        <Button fx:id="delBtn" defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onDeleteHandler" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Delete" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
                                                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="16.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" />
                                                        <!-- <ImageView fitHeight="24.0" fitWidth="24.0">
                                                            <image>
                                                                <Image url="@ClearAll.png" />
                                                            </image>
                                                        </ImageView> -->
                                                        <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClearHandler" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="79.0" text="Clear All" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
                                                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="16.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" />
                                                        <!-- <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="27.0">
                                                            <image>
                                                                <Image url="@excel_logo.gif" />
                                                            </image>
                                                        </ImageView> -->
                                                        <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onExportHandler" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Download" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
                                                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="16.0" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" wrapText="true" />
                                                        <!-- <ImageView fitHeight="30.0" fitWidth="25.0">
                                                            <image>
                                                                <Image url="@printer-icon.gif" />
                                                            </image>
                                                        </ImageView> -->
                                                        <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPrintHandler" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" text="Print" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" styleClass="red-gradient" />
                                                    </children>
                                                </HBox>
                                            </items>
                                        </ToolBar>
                                    </children>
                                    <children>
                                     <ScrollPane prefHeight="340.0"  prefWidth="850.0">
                                        <TableView fx:id="tblViewer" styleClass="tableview" stylesheets="@ClsMain.css" />
                                     </ScrollPane>      
                                    </children>
                                </VBox>
                            </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                </Tab>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Can you help me with this isssue?

Kind Regards,

Comment: the scrollbar for TableView is added automatically

Comment: True, but I am opening that TableView in window and if I resize the window it wont come to the edges means right-end or bottom. Its fixed with height and width.